# Crunching json with python

Tags: python, json, parsing

Echoing my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667359/crunching-xml-with-python) now need to find a way to crunch json down to one line: e.g.

```
{"node0":{
    "node1":{
        "attr0":"foo",
        "attr1":"foo bar",
        "attr2":"value with        long        spaces"
    }
}}
```

would like to crunch down to a single line:

```
{"node0":{"node1":{"attr0":"foo","attr1":"foo bar","attr2":"value with        long        spaces"}}}
```

by removing insignificant white spaces and preserving the ones that are within the value. Is there a library to do this in python?

**EDIT**
Thank you both drdaeman and Eli Courtwright for super quick response!

Comment: The version of Python you're using is somewhat relevant here. json has been part of the standard library since (I think) 2.6

Comment: Using python 2.6, so the suggested solution worked for me great

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(json.loads("""
... {"node0":{
...     "node1":{
...         "attr0":"foo",
...         "attr1":"foo bar",
...         "attr2":"value with        long        spaces"
...     }
... }}
... """))
'{"node0": {"node1": {"attr2": "value with        long        spaces", "attr0": "foo", "attr1": "foo bar"}}}'
```

Comment: Oh, I've almost forgot it... You should use `(',', ':')` as `separators` argument to json.dumps (see documentation). This will make data even more compact.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.6:

```
import json
print json.loads( json_string )
```

Basically, when you use the json module to parse json, then you get a Python dict.  If you simply print a dict and/or convert it to a string, it'll all be on one line.  Of course, in some cases the Python dict will be slightly different than the json-encoded string (such as with booleans and nulls), so if this matters then you can say

```
import json
print json.dumps( json.loads(json_string) )
```

If you don't have Python 2.6 then you can use [the simplejson module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/).  In this case you'd simply say

```
import simplejson
print simplejson.loads( json_string )
```

Comment: Just print'ing json.loads will print Python representation of the data, not JSON-encoded one.